# How to restore stack page in tab from other tab

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have designed an app like this image

[image]

in detail page, I wrote code

```
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.stack = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.navCtrl.length(); i++) {
      let view = this.navCtrl.getByIndex(i);
      this.stack.push({
        page: view.component.name,
        params: view.data
      });
    }
    this.storage.set("stackPage", this.stack); //save stack to storage
 }
```

then I call stack from TAB 2 use function `goToStack()`

```
goToStack(stack){
 this.storage.get('stackpage').then(val=>{
   this.navCtrl.insertPages(1, val);
 });
}
```

but the active tab is TAB 2 I want the active tab to be TAB 1

[image]

can anyone help me to set the active tab to TAB 1?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @SurajRao if TAB 1 is list of book, then book have some table of content and content. in TAB 2 i want to set user activity like last view, bookmark etc.